# Problem with getting min value (first image) from table images and joining to all records from another table

Tags: mysql

I want a result set with all the records from 1 table (tbl_onderdelen) and extra fields like imageCount and image info (image_name, image_path and image_cat) from tbl_images where image_size = 'T' and image_cat = 'onder'

- imageCount => count all the images
- an image (name,path & cat) with the lowest sequence number (image_seq) if there are images for this item.

I have made a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7a99/1

The problem:

- I have in this example 4 records (ID's => 3,4,16 &17)
- List item

there is only 1 image with size 'T' and cat 'onder' (image_id = 360) and related with image_item_id (3) <==> on_id (3)

The result is:

```
on_id   on_titel    imageCount   image_item_id  image_name
3       Mercedes 3      4            3              22591-nummer-17.jpg
16      Mercedes 16     0            (null)         (null)
```

Explanation: in the table tbl_images there are images with image_item_id 4 & 17. 
These images are from the image_cat ‘stock’ or ‘velg’. So, if there is an image with the same image_item_id and not in the image_cat ‘onder’, it will not appear in the result!

The result should be:

```
on_id   on_titel      imageCount  image_item_id  image_name 
  3     Mercedes 3        4       3              22591-nummer-17.jpg
  4     Mercedes 4        0       (null)         (null)  
 16     Mercedes 16       0       (null)         (null)
 17     Mercedes 17       0       (null)         (null)
```

1/ If I do an extra WHERE (image_cat = 'onder')

```
...
     FROM tbl_images 
          JOIN (
                SELECT image_item_id, MIN(image_seq) as seq
                FROM tbl_images p1
                WHERE image_size = 'T'and image_cat = 'onder'
                GROUP BY image_item_id
         ) p1
...
```

than the result is:

```
on_id   on_titel      imageCount  image_item_id  image_name 
  3     Mercedes 3        4       3              22591-nummer-17.jpg
  4     Mercedes 4        2       (null)         (null)  
 16     Mercedes 16       0       (null)         (null)
 17     Mercedes 17       6       (null)         (null)
```

but he still counts the images wrong for id 4 & 17

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (
         SELECT s.on_id, s.on_code, s.on_online, s.on_titel, COUNT(tbl_images.image_id) AS imageCount 
         FROM tbl_onderdelen s
         LEFT JOIN tbl_images ON s.on_id = tbl_images.image_item_id
         GROUP BY s.on_id 
    ) A

LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT tbl_images.image_item_id, tbl_images.image_name, tbl_images.image_path, tbl_images.image_cat
           FROM tbl_images 
           JOIN (
              SELECT image_item_id, MIN(image_seq) as seq
              FROM tbl_images p1
              WHERE image_size = 'T'
              GROUP BY image_item_id
             ) p1
          ON tbl_images.image_item_id = p1.image_item_id AND tbl_images.image_seq  = p1.seq
    ) P

ON A.on_id = P.image_item_id
WHERE (P.image_cat = 'onder' OR P.image_cat IS NULL)
```

Ho can help me? I'm searching already for a long time...

---

Thanks to @IVOGELOV for the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
     SELECT s.vb_id, s.vb_code, s.vb_online, s.vb_merk_band, s.vb_merk_velg, s.vb_desc, s.vb_titel,s.vb_titel_seo, COUNT(tbl_images.image_id) AS imageCount 
     FROM tbl_velgen_banden s
     LEFT JOIN tbl_images ON s.vb_id = tbl_images.image_item_id and image_size = 'T'and image_cat = 'onder'
     GROUP BY s.vb_id 
    ) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_images.image_item_id, tbl_images.image_name, tbl_images.image_path, tbl_images.image_cat
    FROM tbl_images 
    JOIN (
            SELECT image_item_id, MIN(image_seq) as seq
            FROM tbl_images p1
            WHERE image_size = 'T' and image_cat = 'onder'
            GROUP BY image_item_id
        ) p1
        ON tbl_images.image_item_id = p1.image_item_id
          AND tbl_images.image_seq  = p1.seq
    ) P
 ON A.vb_id = P.image_item_id
 WHERE (P.image_cat = 'onder' OR P.image_cat IS NULL)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding additional conditions in the JOIN - like `LEFT JOIN tbl_images ON s.on_id = tbl_images.image_item_id and image_size = 'T'and image_cat = 'onder'` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks! It works! 
I had to add also extra WHERE condition after WHERE image_size = 'T' => ... AND image_cat = 'onder'.